# Efficiency of int vs int[]

Tags: c++, arrays, performance

At the moment I have a postcode validation program which I am writing and I have 6 integer variable declared and named appropriately to the degree to which the postcode matches good postcode standard. Having 6 integers has allowed me to name each one in such a way that what they're counting is very easily visible. However, the code I've written could be a lot neater if I were to use an array of integers to store these counts as I have found I am having to interpret with if statements to get from the regex_match I've found to which integer to increment.

For example, I have currently written:

```
for(int iteration = 0 ; iteration < 6 ; iteration++) {
    expression = testStrings[iteration];
    if(std::regex_match(toTest, expression)) {
        if(iteration == 0) return FullMatch; //place 0 match = Good UK Postcode
        if(iteration == 1) return SyntaxFail; //place 1 match = Poor UK Postcode
        if(iteration == 2) return ZipCodeFail; //place 2 match = Zipcode
        if(iteration == 3) return IrelandFail; //place 3 match = Ireland
        if(iteration == 4) return IrelandFail; //place 4 match = Alternate Ireland
        if(iteration == 5) return CanadaFail; //place 5 match = Canada
    }
}
```

But this could hypothetically be:

```
for(int iteration = 0 ; iteration < 6 ; iteration++) {
    expression = testStrings[iteration];
    if(std::regex_match(toTest, expression)) {
        return PostcodeCount[iteration]
    }
```

Or something similar to account for the fact I've checking two different ways for Irish addresses.

There are other places in the code I've written which currently are explicit but could instead use the array to shorten the amount of code written at the cost of a small amount of readability.

At the moment my program works just fine, and it does everything I want it to do, but I want to use this code to validate around 30,000 postcodes at a time so I'd prefer if it were more efficient than it currently is (though that shouldn't imply it takes acres of time currently). I don't want to sacrifice too much readability if there is little or no efficiency gain.

I have tried to Google for answers to this question, but my Google-fu must be weak tonight, because I have only found web references on the relative efficiency of vectors and arrays, nothing for what I want to know.

Comment: "Efficiency of ..." -- **please nooooooo!** (did you **actually** try running it on 30000 postcodes? was it too slow? this should finish execution within a few milliseconds on modern architectures, especially if you turn on compiler optimizations.)

Comment: Please type in "Performance vs. Readability" in your favorite search engine and read the top hits.

Comment: Or use a `union` and get the efficiency of both worlds

Comment: Lets simply put away the fact that its premature optimization: the ifs are O(n) whereas the array is O(1); if you would use a switch though, they would be basically the same, though the array would still create less overhead (no jumps involved, just simple memory access)

Comment: if-else if-else would surely be more efficient from what you have now ...

Comment: @A4L dont think so, any decent compiler will understand the relationship between these if statements (only checked if the one before failed)

Comment: A switch() statement already uses an array.  One you don't have to initialize yourself.

Comment: I should elaborate: I do more than simply count the postcodes and display the answer, the above is just a snip to exemplify what I was getting at. I have run my code on 40k addresses (which I have pre-compiled so as to know what the answer should be) and it takes a noticeable amount of time to carry out all the operations I have it performing. If the answer to this is that arrays are more efficient then there are several places I could use the answer, not just in this part of my code.

Comment: @A4L No, not really. Just use a compiler that was made after 2000.

Comment: @Paranaix & H2CO3 You're right guys, but will this still be true if there were no return statements?

Comment: @A4L Yes. For a fixed array of regexen. Anyways, as written it doesn't make sense to have a loop anyways. What's the rationale? "NEED MOAR BRANCHES"?

Comment: Obviously the second option is branchless so should be faster and IMO it is more readable semantic-wise.

Comment: It is unclear what "second option" you are referring to, @Etherealone. The "second option" in the question is still the same loop, right (loops are _not_ branchless)

Comment: @sehe there is no comparison of `iteration` variable and no multiple returns accordingly.

Comment: @sehe Loop-unroll will probably eliminate that but otherwise iteration has different value each loop and it should have noticeable impact as there are many `if`s. Yet function altogether probably will take insignificant time in both cases.

Comment: @Etherealone interesting loop unroll would result in exactly [this code](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21356169/85371). I say, KISS. And profile.

Comment: @sehe exactly. I think fixed-size array + offset will also eventually be optimized into that answer, too. In that case, naturally both will perform the same. But array+offset is more readable IMO.

Answer (score 3):

The difference between both solutions will be negligible. The `regex_match` call is probably more costly anyway. BTW your code calls for `switch` statement.

Comment: How on earth does `switch` come in? It's just a linear flow with several early outs

Answer (score 1):

```
if(std::regex_match(toTest, testStrings[0])) return FullMatch; //Good UK
if(std::regex_match(toTest, testStrings[1])) return SyntaxFail; //Poor UK
if(std::regex_match(toTest, testStrings[2])) return ZipCodeFail; //Zipcode
if(std::regex_match(toTest, testStrings[3])) return IrelandFail; //Ireland
if(std::regex_match(toTest, testStrings[4])) return IrelandFail; //Alt Ireland
if(std::regex_match(toTest, testStrings[5])) return CanadaFail; //Canada
```

I would go one step further and just use named variables instead of that array of regex's.

Comment: This is what I'd do. Let ---God--- the compiler sort them out! (And make sure that `testStrings` is actually an array of precompiled regexen)

Answer (score 1):

Performance will not matter regardless of which way you do it. But in order to easily extend the number of tests I would have refactored the loop into something like the following:

```
for (const auto& pc : postcodeTests)
{
   if (std::regex_match(toTest, pc.expression))
   {
      return pc.postcode;
   }
}
```

`postcodeTests` would in this case be any collection containing elements with at least two members: `expression` and `postcode`.